# Where is the configuration for default landing directory

Tags: login, root

When I logging to my company's servers I land in the root. Is this configurable to lets say land in the home ? If yes then where ?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the default working directory when logging in should be `$HOME`. If that isn't where you want, add `cd <desired_directory>` to your `.bash_profile`.

If you're logging in via ssh, you could also do it directly: `ssh -t <server_address> "cd <desired_directory>; bash"`.